# Creating Web App in Sonoma Safari fails due to insufficient permissions

Tags: macos, safari

On macOS 14 Sonoma when I click “Add to dock” to make a web app of any website, Safari shows me an error saying:

```
You don’t have permission to save the file “(website)” in the folder “Applications”. 
To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.”
```

At the same time the `/Applications` folder has proper write access.

Answer (score 1):

Confusingly the error is referring to the `Applications` folder within your home folder. So here's how to fix it:

1. Open Finder and go to your home folder (/Users/yourusername/)
2. Create a new Applications folder here; if it already exists make sure your user has write access by clicking Get info and then adding your user with Read & Write permissions (or you can also do it from Terminal I suppose)
3. Now try creating the Safari web app again!

(Note that the permissions window worked kinda weird for me. This might still be a beta/RC issue. But after a few tries it does work - you just have to click around a few times.)